# Could this blocking be due to lack of semicolon to separate batches?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Looking to reduce blocking and I see the following a lot when running the blocking script from Pinal Dave.

> Example with dummy table names

```
BLOCKING_TREE
    HEAD -  62 drop table if exists live.dbo.connection  select * into live.dbo.connection from [dbo].connection_temp
    |         |------  137 SELECT tr.name AS [Name], tr.object_id AS [ID] FROM sys.triggers AS tr WHERE (tr.parent_class = 0) ORDER BY [Name] ASC
```

Could this be due to the trigger checks done on the DROP statement on SPID 62 still being held during the INSERT, thus blocking SPID 137 which is looking to return TR info?
If it is, would adding a semicolon between the DROP and INSERT free up that lock?

As this happens for many scripts but it can be ages before I see the exact same SP being the head of a blocking tree,  I am looking for advice on whether my train of though is correct or am I potentially wasting time peppering semicolons all over hundreds of legacy/inherited SPs trying to reduce blocking.

Comment: Semicolon isn't a batch separator, it's a statement separator; these are not the same thing.

Comment: To answer your question - no, statement termination has no impact on blocking. Transaction boundaries are the important thing to find along with the locks taken within those transactions and the order in which they are taken. Yes - you are wasting time.

Comment: Semicolons are a good idea. But that is entirely separate from transactions and locking, it's purely a syntax thing

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no.

Longer answer - Semicolons are currently (for the most part) optional in T-SQL. If the presence or absence of them affected blocking behavior, it would suggest that the locks taken (or their scope) would be different is affected. That is in the realm of "extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence".

---

That said, if you're dropping/creating a live table (I see `drop table if exists...`, `select * into...`) in the context of a trigger, I'd strongly expect that to have concurrency issues. I'd recommend either switching to temporary tables or stop dropping/creating the table and instead insert the data from what appears to be a staging table into your live table. But without seeing the trigger definition, it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I'm learning 'on the job' with little local expertise to lean on so I have many gaps in my knowledge. I will seek permission to amend the SP, and the many like it, to utilise temp tables and 'INSERT INTO' to try and minimise the frequency this type of statement might be causing my issues.

Comment: No problem. Just take my recommendation in the context of that it was given "sight unseen" insofar as I'm merely speculating as to what you're doing in your trigger.

Comment: @CoFFeeDeMoN Even temp tables can have concurrency issues if they are dropped and created often enough. They are essentially just normal tables located in tempdb, just with funny names. If you use them in a stored procedure (rather than a plain SQL batch) then there is a certain amount of caching done on the table schema, so that may improve things.

Comment: @Charlieface - agreed and (in retrospect given the OP's self-identified level of SQL knowledge) I should have mentioned this. An alternative to drop/create is "create if not exists" if you're paranoid or just create on the assumption that SQL works the way it should and temp tables don't persist between invocations of your proc.